# What does create method do in gradlePlugin.plugins?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

In the gradle doc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project

The code block is:

```
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("simplePlugin") {
            id = "org.example.greeting"
            implementationClass = "org.example.GreetingPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed it calls `create` method. And I looked the source code. It says:

> Creates a new item with the given name, adding it to this container,
> then configuring it with the given action.

What does it mean? Is it actually used anywhere? Or it can be any name does not really matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`gradlePlugin.plugins`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/devel/GradlePluginDevelopmentExtension.html#getPlugins--) is a `NamedDomainObjectContainer` - which are used by Gradle to hold multiple objects, each with a name.

The documentation on plugin development goes [into more detail](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#declaring_a_dsl_configuration_container) on the usage of `NamedDomainObjectContainer`s.

> Sometimes you might want to expose a way for users to define multiple, named data objects of the same type.
>
> [...]
>
> It’s very common for a plugin to post-process the captured values within the plugin implementation e.g. to configure tasks.

Since the elements of a `NamedDomainObjectContainer` can be any type, there's no specific usage for one. Generally they are used to configure the Gradle project, for example creating specific tasks, configuring source code locations.

Comment: In this case the type is [`PluginDeclaration`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/devel/GradlePluginDevelopmentExtension.html#getPlugins--)